# Netbeans plugin works perfectly while debugging, but not working when the plugin is installed to the IDE

Tags: java, netbeans-6.9, netbeans-plugins

I am currently working on a Java plugin for Netbeans 6.9.1 using the Apache POI api for interfacing with Microsoft documents that has two functions, the first takes data from a properties text file and creates an excel spreadsheet(.xlsx) containing that data, and the second part takes text from a spreadsheet and adds it to a properties text file.

When I run the code in the debugger both of the functions work great. The files get created and edited as they are supposed to, but I ran into problems when I created the NBM from the project and installed the plugin. The import (from .xlsx to .txt) does not do change the contents of the text file. I have checked variables at various times in the code to make sure there's nothing wrong with them there and everything was as it should. The export (.txt to .xlsx) works fine in the plugin, so I'm not sure exactly what's going on. When I start the import it goes through the steps, but nothing ever gets changed or written to the final files.

I'm pretty new to Netbeans so I'm not sure if there is a major difference from debugger to the actual plugin that is affecting how the program acts. Any help

Comment: The problem was creating a temporary file to write to. In the debugger it wrote to the projects folder, whereas when it was installed as a plugin it was creating the temporary file in Program Files. Windows wasn't letting the program get at the file once it was created in that directory so I changed it to create the file in Local App Data instead.

`code`    System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Local Settings\\Application Data" `code`
Glad that it's finally working, wasted a lot of time on such a simple fix, hope this can help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was creating a temporary file to write to. In the debugger it wrote to the projects folder, whereas when it was installed as a plugin it was creating the temporary file in Program Files. Windows wasn't letting the program get at the file once it was created in that directory so I changed it to create the file in Local App Data instead.

```
$    System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Local Settings\\Application Data"
```

Glad that it's finally working, wasted a lot of time on such a simple fix, hope this can help someone else in the future.